# Is it possible to upload a default image for a field

Tags: personal-campaign-pages

While creating a Personal Campaign Page, there is one image upload field (see attached screenshot). Is it possible to attach a default image in case a user does not wish to upload one?
Screenshot: [image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue of default values for PCPs has come up a few times but there are no options currently to do this so it will require some development work.